# How to apply detach feature in browser extension using crossrider?

Tags: browser-extension, crossrider

Can anyone help me regarding the detached feature , which enables the popup.html I have created to detach from the extension and appear as a popup just like in firebug .

Comment: You need to explain the scenario that you are trying to achieve, it's not clear. Describe the sequence of events, the trigger for opening the popup.html and what you mean by "appear as a popup just like in firebug".

Comment: Thank you for your concern @Shlomo ... As you know about the Firebug 2.0.13 Addon for Morzilla browser has detached feature and the results display in a popup . How can I apply that on my html file that is displayed as a dropdown in my browser extension . I am new using crossrider and building browser extensions .

Comment: Actually, I'm not familiar with the Firebug Detached feature, so a link to a page that describes it would be very helpful. In general, you can open a window using the Crossrider API [appAPI.OpenURL](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-openURL) method specifying **where** as _window_ and a **resourcePath**.